# When a new word is coined, should onyomi or kunyomi be used?

Tags: readings, onyomi

Suppose a new word is coined in a novel/manga/video game etc, which is composed of two kanjis, with no kanas. Which reading should I expect to use, kunyomi or on'yomi? If it is on'yomi, should I use Go'on, Kan'on or To'on?

Edit: Sorry for the possible confusion, but I mean, in the situation where I encounter a newly-coined word with no reading attached, how should I know the correct reading?

In Chinese (of which I am a native speaker), readings of a homograph (多音字, characters with multiple readings) are distinguished by meanings, so it's easy to get the correct reading.

Comment: This is hard to answer. It depends on what kanji are used, how they are combined to form the word, whether there are existing words of similar formation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're free to choose!

If the new word is gonna be a place/person name, then the existing convention is that you may use any Kanji and attribute any readings to it, for example, you could use the Kanji 回 and have it read as `BANANA` if you want.

If the terms is not a name, you're still free to choose to assign it the on-reading, the kun-reading, or even a special reading. If I create a new term, let's say, 雨流, I can have it read as うる, うりゅう, あまながし, あめながし, or even a special reading like ゆばし or クール・デ・プルイー or whatever. So long I communicate this with my audience clearly, there's no problem. In fact, giving newly-coined terms in pretty common.

Example of special readings of newly-coined terms:

東京{とうきょう} 喰種{グール}

[青眼の白龍]{ブルーアイズホワイトドラゴン} (Blue eyes white dragon from YuGiOh)

Even in the standard language, there are a TONS a special readings for Kanji pairs, the most common ones being 今日{きょう}、昨日{きのう}、明日{あした} so this concept of special reading is not strange to Japanese people at all.

Comment: "and have it read as `BANANA` if you want." I heard "BANANA" in my head with a stereotypical southern American accent.

Comment: Isn't this question about encountering a new word someone else has created? If a new word appears in a game or something, surely the creators have some idea for how it should be read. Choosing to read such a word as BANANA is probably not going to gain any traction amongst the other fans of the game who encounter the word. They wouldn't know what you're talking about. Maybe I misunderstood the question, though.

Comment: Nowhere does the OP mention it's about reading other's words though. The OP is asking about the rules by which a new Kanji compound can be read.

Comment: It doesn't sound like that to me, especially with the edit about "encounter a newly coined word." I feel like you wouldn't phrase it that way when talking about creating a word yourself. But it's up to the OP what to do with any given answer, so I won't press the issue.

Comment: If someone coins a new word, only ever prints it and doesn't provide furigana, it's that person's fault if people can't discern the intended reading. A video game making up in-world jargon is almost certainly going to either use furigana or have characters voice-act the line, or both.